# Second long argument ignored?

Tags: java, android

I'm hoping I just have some sort of weird typo somewhere but I'm baffled. I have the following code:

```
public void getAvailableStorage() {
        File path = Environment.getDataDirectory();
        StatFs stat = new StatFs(path.getPath());
        long blockSize = stat.getBlockSizeLong();
        long availableStorage = blockSize * stat.getAvailableBlocksLong();
        long totalStorage = blockSize * stat.getBlockCountLong();
        mBackupView.showAvailableStorage(availableStorage, totalStorage);
    }
```

A breakpoint on the last line there shows that totalStorge and availableStorage gets calculated just fine. Moving over to showAvailableStorage();

```
public void showAvailableStorage(long free, long total) {
        float freePercentage = (float)(free/total) * 100;
    }
```

For some reason, only the first argument gets a value. However, this is regardless of what order I pass the values from getAvailableStorage(). The second argument (total) is just ignored breaking at method only gives me a value for the first argument. What am I missing here? Even passing arbitrary values to the method yields the same result.

EDIT: However, this works for some reason...

```
public void showAvailableStorage(long free, long total) {
        long newTotal = total;
        float freePercentage = (float)(free/total) * 100;
    }
```

Comment: many time breakpoints do't work as expected. they show weird value. can you log both the the value before calling the method `showAvailableStorage()` and again log all three value after calulating `freePercentage`.

Comment: Also, if you are not getting the second value total which means the default value of total will be 0. So you should be getting a `DivideByZeroException` there. are you getting that?

Comment: @SaranSankaran You're right. It's seemingly just a debugger bug. The value turns out to actually be correct, it just wasnt showing up in the debugger. Thanks.

Comment: I have posted an answer, please mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many times the debugger doesn't work as expected and shows some weird value. However, your code is correct.

You can try logging the values to find out exact value.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue is seemingly caused by a bug in the debugger. The correct value was indeed passed along but didnt show up in the debugger when stepping through.